# Coordinates from angle and distance in iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps, location, coordinates, angle

In my iPhone app, suppose I have the coordinates of the current location. I want to know the coordinates of a point 10km from here, and 30° North East for example. How do I calculate it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After typing a bunch of formulae out, I realized there's a site that already has it down, so I'm just going to link that instead, [Calculate distance and bearing between two Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).  The section titled "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point" is what you want.  Just convert the degrees to radians (your bearing) and you'll be all set